# Tower of Hanoi without moving directly from dist to temp

Tags: algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

Consider the original tower of Hanoi problem with one extra condition :

- If you have 3 pole A , B and C you are not allowed to move a disc directly from A to B or B to A

that means from the famous recursive solution we are not allowed to move start to temp or temp to start.

```
void hanoi(int n, char start, char temp, char finish){
    if (n== 1)
        cout << start << " -> " << finish;
    else {
        hanoi(n - 1, start, finish, temp);
        cout << start << " -> " << finish;
        hanoi(n - 1, temp, start, finish);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution for this ?

Comment: What makes you think there is a solution?

Comment: you mean there is not ?

Comment: I don't know; you seem to think there is, so I wondered what the basis for that was.

Comment: Of course there is a solution for this. I am sure you can find one just by Googling it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving from A to B directly, just perform an intermediary move A->C->B. If the implementation is correct, it should be always possible to do that.

Comment: the first move is always a -> c and second is a -> b so we get a -> c , a -> c , a -> b

Comment: For the second move, you can do c->b, a->c, b->c